# How can I expand function into a series of exponentially decaying (co)sines?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, laplace-transform

A Fourier series is an expansion of a periodic function into a series of (co)sines.
Non-periodic functions can be expanded using a Fourier transform.
Using some simple steps the transition can be made from a Fourier series to a Fourier transform.
A Fourier transform can be expressed without using complex numbers.

I want to construct similar reasoning ending up with the Laplace transform.

I want to start with expanding a function $f(t)$ in $e^{a_kt} \sin(k\omega_0 t)$ and $ e^{a_kt} \sin(k\omega_0 t)$ 
$$ f(t)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{c_kt}(a_k \sin(k\omega_0 t) \ +  \  b_k \cos(k\omega_0 t)) $$
Slightly reformulated:
$$ f(t)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (A_k \sin(k\omega_0 t) \ +  \  B_k \cos(k\omega_0 t)) $$ where $$ A_k = a_k e^{c_kt} \ and \  B_k = b_k e^{c_kt} $$

I want to arrive at expressions for both the transform and its inverse without using complex numbers.
I want to do the transition to complex numbers as the final step to simplify the expressions.

Can someone help me to get started?

Comment: Related question from same user, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3735325/can-i-create-an-orthogonal-basis-using-exponentially-decaying-cosines

Comment: By the way, you can't use the @-method to notify someone who hasn't taken part in the question.

Comment: But if you want to notify someone who *has* taken part, e.g., me, then you should use the @-method to insure the user gets notified.

Comment: please tell me "reasoning that does not use complex numbers" is an additional requirement to "reasoning that any bachelor-student in physics or engineering can understand".

Comment: not to complicate things: ignore the requirement "reasoning that any bachelor..."
Complex numbers make all the operations easier, but the interpretation is sometimes more complicated.

Comment: "I want to start with expanding a function in ...": I cannot see any difference between the two types of functions you show.

Comment: there is no difference, I adapted the formulation. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your [premise stated here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739881/how-to-interpret-evaluating-lft%cf%83j%cf%89-for-a-specific-%cf%83-for-a-system) is incorrect, so I'll address that first.

The Fourier-transform of the impulse-response, $F(\omega) := \mathscr{F}[f(t)](\omega) \in \mathbb{C}$, of a *linear time-invariant* system is the *ratio* of the system's output to its input when the input is $e^{j\omega t}$ with $\omega \in \mathbb{R}$. If you have instead a purely real input like $\sin(\omega t)$, the output will be $|F(\omega)|\sin\big{(}\omega t + \angle F(\omega)\big{)}$. Note that,
$$
\frac{|F(\omega)|\sin\big{(}\omega t + \angle F(\omega)\big{)}}{\sin(\omega t)} \neq F(\omega)\ \ \text{or}\ \ |F(\omega)|
$$

Similarly, the unilateral Laplace-transform of the impulse-response is the ratio of the output to the input when the input is $e^{s t}h_0(t)$ where $h_0(t)$ is the unit-step function and $s \in \mathbb{C}$. Complex numbers are unavoidable in these definitions, but I don't see why you would insist on avoiding them anyway. A real system's output will still be real if the input is real, don't worry. Considering complex inputs has great utility and unifying beauty.

It is true that $F(\omega)$ is equivalent to the *bilateral* Laplace-transform evaluated on the imaginary axis, provided both transforms converge. In that regard, the Fourier-transform is "contained within" the Laplace-transform, and like you seem to have deduced, since the Fourier-basis $\{e^{j\omega t}\ \forall \omega\}$ was already complete, the values obtained for $\mathcal{R}(s) \neq 0$ in the Laplace-transform are "extra", though be [mindful of caveats](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/15356/30648) related to convergence and possible definition mismatches.

Also notice that the [inverse Laplace-transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Laplace_transform) is not as simple as the inverse Fourier-transform, because the Laplace-transform is not associated with a minimal and orthogonal basis. All in all, I think this makes the original pursuit of your question moot. The steps used in the derivation of the Fourier-coefficients *rely on orthogonality*. It then becomes somewhat unclear what you are even after - a proof of the inverse Laplace-transform that "feels" like that of the Fourier-transform? Hopefully that helps you see why people have been a little confused in the [couple places](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3739028/interpretation-of-the-relation-between-laplace-transform-and-fourier-transform) you've posted this question.

Comment: "the input is $e^{st} h_0(t)$ where h0(t) is what I was looking for.

Comment: I want to construct the reasoning in real numbers first and then in the conclusion jump to complex numbers and then in a second-round construct things using complex numbers. I know it is all nicer in complex numbers, but it is more difficult to interpret.

Comment: @BartVanderbeke [This article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_response_formula) should help you see / further confirm the relationship between the Laplace transform and exponential inhomogeneities in linear time-invariant systems. Also in this [PDF from MIT](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/readings/supp_notes/MIT18_03S10_sup.pdf) on page 48, Remark 10.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

$$f{\left(t\right)}=\frac{1}{2\pi j}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(s\right)}e^{+st}ds}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=\frac{1}{2\pi j}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)}e^{\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)t}d\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=\frac{1}{2\pi j}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)}e^{\sigma t}e^{\left(j\omega\right)t}d\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=e^{\gamma t}\frac{1}{2\pi j}\lim_{T\to
\infty}{\int_{\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)}e^{\left(j\omega\right)t}d\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=e^{\gamma t}\frac{1}{2\pi j}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}e^{\left(j\omega\right)t}d\left(j\omega\right)}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=e^{\gamma t}\frac{j}{2\pi j}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}e^{\left(j\omega\right)t}d\left(\omega\right)}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=e^{\gamma t}\frac{1}{2\pi}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\left(\int_{\gamma-jT}^{\gamma+0j}F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}e^{\left(j\omega\right)t}d\left(\omega\right)+\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma+0j}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}e^{\left(j\omega\right)t}d\left(\omega\right)}\right)}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=e^{\gamma t}\frac{2}{2\pi}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\left(\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma+0j}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}\frac{\left(e^{\left(j\omega\right)t}+e^{\left(-j\omega\right)t}\right)}{2}d\left(\omega\right)}\right)}$$

$$f{\left(t\right)}=e^{\gamma t}\frac{2}{2\pi}\lim_{T\to\infty}{\int_{\gamma+0j}^{\gamma+jT}F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}\cos{\left(\omega t\right)}d\omega}$$

$$f{\left(t\right).e^{-\gamma t}}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}\cos{\left(\omega t\right)}d\left(\omega\right)$$

$$f{\left(t\right).e^{-\gamma t}}=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left(F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}\right)$$

$$\mathcal{F}\left(f{\left(t\right).e^{-\gamma t}}\right)=F{\left(\gamma+j\omega\right)}$$

$$\mathcal{F}\left(f{\left(t\right).e^{-\gamma t}}\right)=\mathcal{L}\left(f{\left(t\right)}\right)$$

When $\gamma=0$:
$$\mathcal{F}\left(f{\left(t\right).e^{0}}\right)=\mathcal{L}\left(f{\left(t\right)}\right)\  when\  \gamma=0$$
$$\mathcal{F}\left(f{\left(t\right)}\right)=\mathcal{L}\left(f{\left(t\right)}\right)\  when\  \gamma=0$$

So the conclusion is 'the expansion in the Laplace transform' uses the Fourier transform, but it is the Fourier transform of the original function $f\left(t\right)$ multiplied with exponential decay $e^{-\gamma t}$.

Is there any literature developing a similar deduction?

Can anyone help by clarifying how to interpret calculating the Fourier transform of a function $f\left(t\right)$ multiplied with $e^{-\gamma t}$?

Comment: This may bring the necessary inspiration: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n2y7n6jw5d0

Comment: This article addresses the topic: http://www.cambridge.org/us/features/chau/webnotes/chap2laplace.pdf