# Can I create an orthogonal basis using exponentially decaying (co)sines?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, exponential-function, orthogonality

How can I create a basis using functions of the shape $e^{a_kt} \sin(k\omega_0 t) \ and  \  e^{a_kt} \cos(k\omega_0 t)$?
What would be the specific dot-product/scalar-product to be able to construct this basis?

I need it to expand a function as shown below:

$$ f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{c_kt}(a_k \sin(k\omega_0 t) \ +  \  b_k \cos(k\omega_0 t)) $$

I am still thinking about how to best formulate the problem.
Maybe it is better expressed as below:

$$ f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (A_k \sin(k\omega_0 t) \ +  \  B_k \cos(k\omega_0 t)) $$
where
$$ A_k = a_k e^{c_kt} \ and \  B_k = b_k e^{c_kt} $$

Comment: Basis of what?${}$

Comment: Generally speaking, given any linearly independent set in a real or complex vector space, you can define an inner product which makes that set orthogonal. But I suppose you have some space in mind and you would like the inner product generate some standard topology on that space.

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully this clarifies what I need.

Comment: Would not it better to sum over $k$?

Comment: Are you sure this is the expression you want? This is not linear in the coefficients $a_k,b_k$ at all.

Comment: @tomasz: I have tried to make the question somewhat more clear

Comment: Related question from same user, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734713/how-can-i-expand-function-into-a-series-of-exponentially-decaying-cosines

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no!
Or at least, there is no need to.
I asked the question because I wanted to arrive at the Laplace transform.
The reasoning that makes more sense is shown in [how-can-i-expand-function-into-a-series-of-exponentially-decaying-cosines](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734713/how-can-i-expand-function-into-a-series-of-exponentially-decaying-cosines)
The basis remains the infinite row of (co)sines, the exponential occurs without the need for it to be part of a basis.